# Proof by induction that $\frac1{n+1} + \frac1{n+2} + \ldots + \frac1{2n} \geq \frac7{12}$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

The question is prove that for every integer greater than or equal to 2

$$\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2n} \geq \frac{7}{12}$$

So far I have

Base case let $p(2)$
\begin{align*} 
\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2+2} + \frac{1}{4} & \geq \frac{7}{12}\\
\frac{5}{6} & \geq \frac{7}{12}
\end{align*}

therefore base case is true.
Let's assume it is a true statement for $p(n+1)$ for all $n$ greater than or equal to $2.$

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(n+1)+1} + \frac{1}{(n+1)+2} + \frac{1}{2(n+1)} \geq \frac{7}{12}\\
\frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+3} + \frac{1}{2n+2} \geq \frac{7}{12}
\end{align*}

then I wrote that if $n$ is greater than or equal to $2$ is a true statement then the inequality is true. This is a proof by induction and I'm not sure if I concluded properly

Comment: Please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial for proper typesetting. It will help everyone better understand your question.

Comment: Oh perfect thank you very much

Comment: The base case is for $n=2$ is actually $1/3+1/4=7/12$

Comment: 1/3+1/4+1/4 =5/6

Comment: @user212401 No, there are only two terms in the $n=2$ case. The ellipsis form of the formula really only definitely indicates the start and end points and shows the general nature of interim points; it doesn't set a minimum number of terms or indeed the maximum number of terms - you are left to infer the exact quantity. In this case, there are $n$ terms in each sum, one each for all the numbers from $n+1$ to $2n$.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883670/show-that-the-inequality-holds-frac1n-frac1n1-frac12n-ge-fr and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/508664/proving-frac1n1-frac1n2-cdots-frac12n-frac1324-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what would be p(n+1)? think about where that falls in your solution. p(n+1) is 1/(2n+2)

Answer (score 2):

Consider $P(n+1) - P(n)$.  This difference has only three terms, all the middle terms cancel.  And looking at those three terms you can easily show $P(n+1)-P(n)>0$.  That proves that if $P(n)>7/12$ then $P(n+1)$ must also be.

Comment: so is my answer wrong then? I have a midterm coming up soon and I'm confused on this subject. Would p(n+1) consist of 1/[(n+1)+1]+ 1/[(n+1)+2]+ 1/2(n+1) and p(n) be the regular 1/(n+1)+ 1/(n+2)+ 1/2n and you're Saying to subtract the two equations

Comment: Yes your answer is not correct.  Note how the question contains "$\dots$" but you seem to have lost them in your answer and they make all the difference.

Comment: Since P(2) is the statement $$\frac{1}{2 + 1} + \frac{1}{2 \cdot 2} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{4}{12} + \frac{3}{12} = \frac{7}{12} \geq \frac{7}{12}$$ the assumption should be that $P(n) \geq \frac{7}{12}$.  However, $P(n) > \frac{7}{12}$ for $n > 2$ for the reason you cited.

Comment: So what would be p(n+1) in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The three dots $\ldots$ are an ellipsis, indicating continuation of the preceding trend of terms up to the final term.

There are only two terms in the $n=2$ case. The ellipsis form of the formula really only definitely indicates the start point, the end point and the general nature of interim points; it doesn't set a minimum number of terms or indeed the maximum number of terms - you are left to infer the exact quantity.

In this case, there are $n$ terms in each sum, one each for all the numbers from $n+1$ to $2n$. So for the sake of clarity, here are a few terms:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} &= \frac{7}{12} \tag{n=2} \\[0.5em]
\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} &= \frac{37}{60} \tag{n=3} \\[0.5em]
\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} &= \frac{533}{840} \tag{n=4} \\[0.5em]
\end{align}$$

You can see that that $\frac{1}{3}$ has been replaced by $\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6}$ in going from $n=2$ to $n=3$, and  $\frac{1}{4}$ has been replaced by $\frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8}$ in going from $n=3$ to $n=4$. This should indicate the correct line of the induction argument.

Comment: Okay so does p(n+1) in this question consist of 1/(n+1) + 1/(n+2)+ 1/2n? @joffan

Comment: And p(n) is just the first term of 1/(n+1) +1/2n

Comment: No, it's the sum of one over **all** the numbers between $n+1$  and $2n$ inclusive: $$p(n) = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{1}{k} $$ ... if we want to be formal about it.